# mobile navigation bar using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, responsive-design

i'm trying to design my first website, I've built my menu bar which has a couple of levels. everything works fine. now i want to make it mobile-friendly.

so i want to make the levels open up on click using jquery. i've managed to open to the first level but when i click on the second level i can't seem to open the third level...

here's the code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      jQuery("#menu-trigger").click(function() {
        jQuery("ul#nav").slideToggle();
      });
      $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 500) {
          $('ul#nav').removeAttr('style');
        }
      });
      $('ul#nav li').click(function() {
          if ($(window).width() <= 500) {
            $(this).find('ul').not('ul .submenu2').slideToggle();

          });

        $('ul#nav li ul .submenu').click(function() {
          $(this).find('ul .submenu2').slideToggle();
        });
      });
```

```css
#menu-trigger {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#nav li {
  float: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #d5dce4;
  position: relative;
}
ul#nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
ul#nav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
}
ul#nav a {
  width: 100%;
}
ul#nav ul.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: static;
}
ul#nav ul.submenu2 {
  display: none;
  position: static;
}
ul#nav li:hover .submenu {
  display: none;
}
ul#nav .submenu li:hover .submenu2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <span id="menu-trigger"> menu </span>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">what is it?</a><span class="darrow">▼</span>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="aboutthesystem.html">about</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="systemobjective.html">objectives</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="systemimplementation.html">implementation</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">5th grade</a><span class="darrow">▼</span>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">geography</a><span class="larrow">&#9666;</span>
        <ul class="submenu2">
          <li><a href="5thgradegeographyworkpage.html">work page</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="5thgradegeographyexplenation.html">explenation</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="5thgradegeographyexemples.html">exemples</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="5thgradegeographyreflections.html">reflections</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

it's my first attempt at web design so i'm sorry for the bad code...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See your code for third level `submenu2` is the class of `ul` element so remove the space between

Try :

```
$('ul#nav li ul .submenu').click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul.submenu2').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/nsujjoje/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("#menu-trigger").click(function(){
    jQuery("ul#nav").slideToggle();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 500){
        $('ul#nav').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
$('ul#nav li').click(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 500){
    $(this).find('ul').not('ul .submenu2').slideToggle();
    }
});

$('ul#nav li ul .submenu').click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul.submenu2').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
#menu-trigger{
    display:inline-block;
}
ul#nav li {

    float:none;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #d5dce4;
    position:relative;
}
ul#nav li :last-child{
    border-bottom:none;
}
ul#nav {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:140px;
}
ul#nav a {
width: 100%;
}
ul#nav ul.submenu {
    display:none;
    position: static;
}
ul#nav ul.submenu2 {
display: none;
position: static;
}
ul#nav li:hover .submenu {
display: none;
}

ul#nav .submenu li:hover .submenu2 {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="menu-trigger"> menu </span>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="index.html" >home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >what is it?</a><span class="darrow">▼</span>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li ><a href="aboutthesystem.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="systemobjective.html">objectives</a></li>
        <li><a href="systemimplementation.html">implementation</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li ><a href="#" >5th grade</a><span class="darrow">▼</span>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">geography</a><span class="larrow">&#9666;</span>
            <ul class="submenu2">
                <li ><a href="5thgradegeographyworkpage.html">work page</a></li>
                <li ><a href="5thgradegeographyexplenation.html">explenation</a></li>
                <li ><a href="5thgradegeographyexemples.html">exemples</a></li>
                <li ><a href="5thgradegeographyreflections.html">reflections</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JS executing only when your browser width less than 500px as per your login :)

Comment: still doesn't work... the first level opens just fine. however when you click on the second level (i.e click on  <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">geography</a>) the menu closes instead of opening "submenu2"...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $(this).children('.submenu').slideToggle();
```

In this way you don't have limit of level. Every sub-level have the same class .submenu
.children([selector ]) method allows us to search through the children of these elements in the DOM tree